# Using regex for validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to validate the telephone number using the regix.  but it is giving me error:

```
  $validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'name'=>'required',
        'telephone'=>'regix:^[[0-9]\-\+]{9,15}$|required|unique:telephone',
        'email'=>'unique:telephone',]);
```

the error is:

> Method [validateRegix] does not exist.

Comment: What is `regix`? Is this some new and improved technology? Otherwise, I'm assuming you meant `Regex`

Comment: This not the answer machine or the syntax checking please at least see your code carefully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'name'=>'required',
    'telephone'=>'regex:^[[0-9]\-\+]{9,15}$|required|unique:telephone',
    'email'=>'unique:telephone',]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`regix` does not exist. `regex` exists.